# Не получается использоваться annotation Lombok

Tags: java, аннотации

Пользуюсь `Community` версией `IntelliJ Idea`. Подгрузил через `Maven` `Lombok`, `springboot`.Пытаюсь использовать аннотации `Lombok` `@Getter @Setter`, поставил галочку `Enable annotation processing`. Но, получить возможность вызвать `getter setter` не получил. Как по фиксить?

Comment: Допишите в вопросе IDE в которой вы работаете + добавили ли вы библиотеку, плагин и перезагружали ли вы IDE после установки?

Comment: @Komdosh, так лучше раскрыл вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Все дело было в плагине Lombok. IDE было не достаточно, что я его просто подключил как зависимость в Maven. Нужно было скачать и установить плагин с репозитория.